# android large amount of data search with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

hi i have an android app with a large amount of data on a mysql database i want to implement autocomplete search on my app but i do not know how do it fast because %like% operator on php is so slow how can i do it with index ? i try this

```
<?php
include_once ('db.php');
$search = $_POST['test'];
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Connection faild";
}else{
    $con->query("SET NAMES utf8");    
    $q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM goods WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('$search')");

    $arr =array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
        {
        $arr[] =$row;
        }
    echo json_encode($arr);

}
```

` but it only working when i send the full name of the product

Comment: If you are looking for something fast, have a look at elasticsearch

Comment: @Eakethet thats great thank a lot

Comment: maybe you can create an index for the column you are searching against. As far as I know that will speed up the query. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp, https://www.bayt.com/en/specialties/q/59171/what-are-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-indexing-in-database/

Answer (score 0):

Try to select only columns you need. Don't use `*`.

Comment: but i want all of them i try indexing and i think its worked

Comment: Oh yea, you can try with Indexing. I just suggesting like my friend do when he have many of data. When he change to select only what he need, the process go faster.